# When will bootstrapping struggle to provide an accurate distribution?

Tags: sampling, bootstrap

Can someone give an example of a statistic for which bootstrapping might struggle to provide an accurate sampling distribution?

Comment: I googled bootstrap failure. Here is the first listed link http://www.win.tue.nl/~rmcastro/AppStat2013/files/note_on_bootstrap_failure.pdf .  Or google bootstrapping failure.  There are many examples provided in papers and books.

Comment: Bootstrap works less well on highly skewed distribution or the original sample size is insufficient.